# Ionic Storage / Local Storage Limitations

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am a complete newbie to Ionic and Cordova and have started to build an app that will record about 300 data points / hour each consisting of a couple of IDs and a date and time stamp. (A few hours max.) I am wondering about using Local Storage vs SQLite?

If I can use Local Storage at least during development and abstract that via Ionic Storage, I see an advantage and then move to SQLite when I get closer to building a Cordova wrapped app.

Just wondering if this is a common / reasonable approach? An approach that will allow me to deploy to my local browser. Or is this going to trip me up in the short term?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question,
You should go with Sqlite from the start as localStorage has quite a few limitations.
1.Local storage cannot store more than 5MB of data.
2. Vulnerable (In this sense, the data can be lost due to some work done in the browser)

You can use the ionic storage along with Sqlite for your key-value store. If you want granular control, You can use the Sqlite interface as well along side the key-value store. (i.e), Ionic will maintain the kv store as a seperate table and your custom Relational tables seperately.

As for the performance, Sqlite is a bit slow compared to localStorage but It does not block the DOM unlike localStorage which is good from a usability perspective.

Comment: I have used this assuming its platform independent. Sadly it only works on Google Chrome on Android and Windows. I tested it on Firefox, Safari on desktop and iPad but without luck. It didn't even work in Chrome running on iPad.

Comment: You want your ionic app to run on the browser?? When using your brower, Cordova plugins will not be available and hence, you will not be able to use sqlite. I thouth you wanted to build it into an app..

Comment: Yes, eventually. It works in Chrome though. I have removed sqlite and now it works on all browsers. The docs state that Ionic 2 Storage take care of the underlying storage depending on whats available, which is not true at the moment.

Comment: Probably a bug.. which version of Ionic are you using? Btw.. Ionic just released the full 2.0.0 ^__^

Comment: I thought the same. I am running 2.0.0-rc.4. I know about the final :D! Will update later today.

Answer (score 1):

I believe ionic 2 storage will select best storage option automaticaly.
If you installed cordova sqlite later-on and ionic 2 storage will use that.
You won't need to change any of your code.

Comment: I agree but if I treat SQLite as a KV no-sql store, will performance be OK? Or is doing so contrary to SQLite's design goal? When you wrap SQLite in Ionic Storage, everything becomes a KV store.